# Python - Split multiline string by extreme brackets

Tags: python, split, multiline, curly-braces

I created function which split multiline string by brackets and appends his parts to list.

example:

```
example = '''{First,
                              {[string]}},
                   {[Second,
                               {[(string)]}]},
                   {Third string}'''


start = 0
results = []
count = 0
for i in range(len(example)):
    if example[i] == '{':
        if count == 0:
            start = i
        count -=1
    if example[i] == '}':
        count +=1
        if count == 0:
            results.append(example[start:i+1])

print(len(results))
print(results)
```

The output of this is (and it is correct, list of 3 elements):

```
3
['{First,\n                              {[string]}}', '{[Second,\n                               {[(string)]}]}', '{Third string}']
```

My problem is, when I add "extra" opened and closed brackets somewhere in string:

```
example = '''{First,
                              {[s{tring]}},
                   {[Second,
                               {[(string)]}]},
                   {Third st}ring}'''
```

My function return me (list of only 1 element):

```
1
['{First,\n                              {[s{tring]}},\n                   {[Second,\n                               {[(string)]}]},\n                   {Third st}ring}']
```

It is possible to avoid this situation and split string only by extreme brackets? If you don't understand my question, please feel free to asking!

EDIT:

I want to also mention that between brackets could be anything like char, integers, commas, dots etc.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is the following

```
l = [] 
for line in example.split('\n'): 
    if ']' in line: 
        s = f"{l[-1]}\n{line}" 
        l[-1] = s 
        else: 
            l.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to reply you kaihami in answer because of better readable of code. Your function doesn't work for more specify string like:

```
example = '''[{This,
                      {{is,'more'},
                       [{specify,
                            string}}}'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this want you want?

```py
import re

example = '''{First,
                              {[s{tring]}},
                   {[Second,
                               {[(string)]}]},
                   {Third st}ring}'''


elements = re.split(r'{*},', example)

>>> [
    '{First,\n                              {[s{tring]}',
    '\n                   {[Second,\n                               {[(string)]}]',
    '\n                   {Third st}ring}'
]
```

Comment: I think is better but what if inside of string will be similar character like "},"? I want to mention, that between extreme brackets could be anything, every char, integer, commas, dots etc.